# Midpoint of a segment

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html):

> **Exercise 2.2**
>
> Consider the problem of
>   representing line segments in a plane.
>   Each segment is represented as a pair
>   of points: a starting point and an
>   ending point. Define a constructor
>   make-segment and selectors
>   start-segment and end-segment that
>   define the representation of segments
>   in terms of points. Furthermore, a
>   point can be represented as a pair of
>   numbers: the x coordinate and the y
>   coordinate. Accordingly, specify a
>   constructor make-point and selectors
>   x-point and y-point that define this
>   representation. Finally, using your
>   selectors and constructors, define a
>   procedure midpoint-segment that takes
>   a line segment as argument and returns
>   its midpoint (the point whose
>   coordinates are the average of the
>   coordinates of the endpoints). To try
>   your procedures, you'll need a way to
>   print points:
>
> ```
> (define (print-point p)
>   (newline)
>   (display "(")
>   (display (x-point p))
>   (display ",")
>   (display (y-point p))
>   (display ")"))
> ```

I wrote the following solution:

```
(define (make-segment a b) (cons a b))
(define (start-segment l) (car l))
(define (end-segment l) (cdr l))

(define (make-point x y) (cons x y))
(define (x-point p) (car p))
(define (y-point p) (cdr p))

(define (sum . l) (if (zero? (length l)) 0 (+ (car l) (apply sum (cdr l)))))
(define (average . l) (/ (apply sum l) (length l)))

(define (midpoint seg)
  (make-point (average (x-point (start-segment seg)) 
                       (x-point (end-segment seg)))
              (average (y-point (start-segment seg))
                       (y-point (end-segment seg)))))

(define (print-point p)
  (newline)
  (display "(")
  (display (x-point p))
  (display ",")
  (display (y-point p))
  (display ")"))

(define seg-1 (make-segment (make-point 3 4)
                            (make-point 8 10)))
(print-point (midpoint seg-1))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definitions of `make-segment` and `make-point` can be simply bound to `cons`; you may do the same for accessors.

```
(define make-segment cons)
(define start-segment car)
(define end-segment cdr)

(define make-point cons)
(define x-point car)
(define y-point cdr)
```

Your definition of `sum` is similar to how `+` works.  You may use `+` instead in your definition of `average`.

```
(define (average . l) (/ (apply + l) (length l)))
```

Notice the repetition of code in your definition of `midpoint`--you create a new point out of the averages of each coordinate of the two end-points that describe the line segment.  You may abstract out the calculation of averages either by writing your own helper function or by using the built-in `map` function, like so:

```
(define point->coordinate-accessors (list x-point y-point))
(define (midpoint seg)
  (apply make-point (map (lambda (point->coordinate)
                           (average (point->coordinate (start-segment seg))
                                    (point->coordinate (end-segment seg))))
                         point->coordinate-accessors)))
```

This definition is general enough to handle midpoint calculation in as many dimensions as handled by `make-point` and `point->coordinate-accessors`.